# Create folders within folders

Tags: python, python-os

My code doesn't work, the intention was to create folders within folders.

```
import os

path = "D:\DOCS\Desktop"
n_folders = 100
x = 0
y = 0



os.chdir(path)
os.mkdir("Initial_Folder")

Second_Layer = []

while x < len(Second_Layer):
    while y < int(n_folders)+1:
        os.chdir(path + "\Initial_Folder")
        os.mkdir("\SecondLayer" + str(x))
        Second_Layer.append(x)
        y = y + 1
os.chdir(path + "\Initial_Folder"+"\SecondLayer" + str(x))
os.mkdir("\ThirdLayer" + str(y))
x = x + 1
```

Comment: Don't put a backslash at the beginning of `SecondLayer`. That makes it an absoluete pathname, so it tries to create it in a root folder, not the current folder.

Comment: You can use [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to create all the directories at once.

Comment: Get in the habit of using raw strings when you write Windows pathnames. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/how-should-i-write-a-windows-path-in-a-python-string-literal